# What is the best way to work with REST WebService and Session management?

Tags: rest, spring-restcontroller

I want to develop a java application with REST web services, as it will have browser client and mobile client. My concern is session management, could anyone suggest me what is the best and recommended way to manage the session. Scenario: An employee will login and then he will call for other services like salary details, work hour details, permanent address etc. Here all these details will be exposed as individual REST web service. After login of employee any further request like request to see the permanent address will be REST service call. Please provide me the best and recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario where you want to support mobile as well as web application, token based authentication and session handling can be a good approach you can follow.

You can either go with existing token based third party API's like (OAuth2) or you can create your own token based session management system.

**Proposed Solution :**

1. Whenever your application get's first hit create and save the random token (say 64 bit random generated string).
2. Mobile and Web Application will save this token in it's memory and send this token in headers every time it makes a webservice call.
3. You will need one web service which will accept all your request and redirect request to your application only when token is valid. If token is invalid it deny access to the applicaton service. (Gateway7 works in same way)
4. You can pass a key for every webservice url. say app.xyz is my identifier. Which points to xyz url of my application 'app'. So your url's will be maintained at server and client will only have identifiers and one URL of your token validator application say 'Token Handler'.
5. So in this 'Token Handler' application you can set your session time. This will be time for which your token will be valid. So if you don't get any hit from that particular user for say 15 minutes then you will mark it as invalid token for next request.

Please let me know we can have discussion if you need any additional help on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing the answer. Roshan I am very much new to this type of implementation. Could you please  share some code base/ git link if you know. A sample project with the same requirement will be a great help.

Comment: I don't have any git codebase but yes this link can help you a little to understand the flow https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-for-java